# Define global random variable in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

I know that you might think that this is a repetitive question, but no. How do you have a global variable inside a function and keep the random number? Like `var randomNum = round(random(1, 10))` and say that it comes out as a 2, can I keep the 2 in any way?

Comment: Ehhh... `randomNum` keeps the 2

Comment: Declare the variable outside the function and set the value inside the function without `var` keyword..

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using 'use strict' inside function or in javascript file.
So you can define :

```
random=round(random(1,10));
```

It will take random as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
// randomnum can be accessed here

function yourfunction() {
    randomNum = round(random(1, 10);

    //can also be accessed here
}
```

Removing `var` auto sets to GLOBAL.